# Why can't execute SCHEMA_NAME.PACKAGE_NAME.PROCEDURE, Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, schema, package, procedure

I have a schema A, Package B and Procedure C. B is in A schema and C is in B's Package Body.

It works fine when I say:

```
Begin 
Exec B.C;
END;
```

But it throw an error when I say:

```
Begin
Exec A.B.C;
END;

Error report:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 12:
PLS-00302: component 'B' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 4:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I log in as A so it's in A's schema.
and 
SELECT * FROM user_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME = 'B';
shows package and package body both valid.

Comment: Well the answer to this question is:

Never name your Synonymy with SCHEMA name.

In this case there are one private synonymy and one public synonymy that causing the issue.

Comment: You should put this in the form of an answer.

Comment: What is `Exec`?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and found the issue. I will write here the answer to close this problem and help other people.

In my case, my user A have execute privilege on a procedure B(just a procedure, not a package, but it's the same). When the user tries to run:

```
Begin 
Exec A.B;
END;
```

Get the error:

```
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 7:
PLS-00302: component 'B' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

**Problem:** That's because a public synonym with name A was created in the database. This is an old database and I am just the DBA, not the developer, but in this case the developer was an uninspired developer. He used 4 types of objects with the same name: user, table, tablespace and public synonym. A public synonym named A in front of a table named A.

**Solution:** Because you don't know exactly who is using that public synonym I had to found another solution instead of deleting the public synonym. I created a private synonym for that procedure. Now the user can skip the owner of procedure in the execution code and ignore the public synonym. This problem appears in Oracle Database 10.2.0.4.

```
Begin 
Exec B;
END;
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**Conclusion:** Never use a public/private synonym with the name of the schema.

Hope to help someone. If I didn't made myself clear, please leave a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Fix **syntax error** in the package, this is a generic PL/SQL compile error message.

Check error points (`line 2, column 12`) in the PL/SQL where the syntax error occurred, correct it and then try recompiling your code.

```
Component 'B' must be declared.
```

After that grant EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE to allow user 'A' execute privileges for packages and procedures in the data dictionary.

```
grant EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE to A;
```

Comment: Why would you grant EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE?